# How do I decide which ambassador to assassinate?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

In the city of Ysa, I was approached by Ambassador Keen, who gave me the **Uprising** quest, which requires me to assassinate Ambassador Brenner. However, if I speak to Ambassador Brenner about it, she in turn wants me to murder Ambassador Keen. Since letting them both lives earns me no experience points, and I like experience points, that isn't a valid option for me and I seem to have a decision to make.

[image]

The only short term difference I see is that if I kill Keen, I'm supposed to deliver the daggers somewhere. If I kill Brenner, I'm supposed to dispose of the daggers. They're lousy daggers, so what happens to them doesn't particularly concern me.

Does the decision over who to kill have any impact on the overall story or future quests?

Comment: I never actually talked to Brenner, just killed her, so I can't say what effect killing Keen might have, but I can say that at no point in the game did I ever see any consequence for killing Brenner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you talk to Brenner and accept killing Keen (and she gives you the daggers) then you do not have a choice - if you go back and kill Brenner, then you cannot loot the daggers and the quest is stuck (as happened to me).

If you then proceed to kill Keen as well, you fail the quest entirely.

As it is listed as a side quest, I have serious doubts that it affects the story in any way.

After you kill Brenner, the daggers do become regular items even if you cannot progress in the quest. I managed to salvage them. Don't know if I totally broke the quest.

Comment: The fact that you can fail it has me more convinced that it doesn't have much effect than the fact that it's a side quest.